# Pushing first visible item using RecylerView

Tags: android, android-animation, android-recyclerview

When an new item is added at position 0, the animation is not seen because the old item is not pushed by the new one.

Is it possible to change the default animation to achieve that the new added item pushes the old first one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code to the place where u change the adapter contents (does not matter before or after).

```
if (layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0) {
    layoutManager.scrollToPosition(0);
}
```